# Using fgets() together with strcmp() strcmp is not properly comparing

Tags: c, fgets, strcmp

My current task is to code a function that's given a `FILE` pointer and a pointer to a string. The function should analyze how many times the string occurs in the given file and return the value as a whole number. It also needs to pay attention to case sensitivity. In my current program, I take the word "dog" as a string to be found in the file. But it keeps giving me 0 even tho the .txt file has the word dog three times in it. This is my first post here and I checked the other posts about this topic, but they couldn't fix it.

This is what I tried:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int searchAndCount(FILE *fp, const char *searchWord) {
    int count = 0;
    char buffer[4096];
    
    while ((fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) != NULL) { 
        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
        if (strcmp(buffer, searchWord) == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int searchedWord;
    const char *c = "dog";
    
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("File couldn't open properly");
        return 1;
    }
    searchedWord = searchAndCount(fp, c);
    printf("The word 'dog' occurs %d-times in the file\n", searchedWord);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

my test.txt looks like this:

```
dog dog dogoggo dog.
```

and I get this:

```c
The word 'dog' occurs 0-times in the file
```

Edit:
So judging from the comments, it seems like i need to implement `strtok()` i will be researching this function.

But using:

```c
int searchAndCount(FILE *fp, const char *searchWord) {
    int count = 0;
    char buffer[4096];
    
    while ((fscanf(fp, "%4095s", buffer)) == 1) { 
        if (strcmp(buffer, searchWord) == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

more or less solved the problem whereas " dog. " does not get counted because of the dot.

Solution:

```c
int searchAndCount(FILE *fp, const char *searchWord) {
    int count = 0;
    char buffer[4096];
    
    for (;;) {
        fscanf(fp, "%*[^a-zA-Z]");
        if (fscanf(fp, "%4095[a-zA-Z]", buffer) != 1)
            break;
        if (strcmp(buffer, searchWord) == 0)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Carefully review exactly what strcmp() does and consider how that relates to - but is different than - what you want to accomplish. strcmp is comparing perfectly fine, but your code doesn't (yet) do what you want to do.

Comment: (a) Remember that `fgets()` includes the newline in the returned data when it fits in the provided buffer.  (b) Remember that `strcmp()` looks for an exact match; it looks as though you probably want to search for the given string within the string read by `fgets()`.  There's a different function for that task.

Comment: Simple text comparison will not work if you want to differentiate "dog" from "doggogo". You need to split your line into words before you can compare it. And remember that each line can hold the word more than once.

Comment: You probably would want to research the use of the "strkok" function which would split up the read string into separate strings.

Comment: `buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';` is a hacker's delight: Consider the UB that occurs when the first character _read_ by `fgets()` is a _null character_.

Comment: How fast do you want? [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Or when the input data ends without a `\n`.  Or on Windows when the file is in binary mode and lines end with `\r\n`.

Comment: You're testing whether the _entire line_ is equal to "dog", so you're getting the right answer.

Comment: @R0gue, you can post your own answer, below.  There it can get rated like other answers.  Do not post your answer in the question.

Comment: @R0gue, What is the desired result from input "dog dog dogoggo dog." with key "dog."?  Note the _key_ has a `.` in it.

Comment: @R0gue,  "But using: `int searchAndCount( ... ` solved the problem !" --> Using your fix,  code reports "The word 'dog' occurs 2 times in the file", yet you have requirement "... has the word dog three times in it.".  So is your fixed code wrong or is the requirement wrong or what?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You are correct. The "fix" doesn't take into consideration that the last dog has a ```.``` in it and therefore doesn't count it. At best i'd like to have that one counted as well. I assume that if i get the program to ignore the ```.``` and count the "dog" before that then the "dog" in "dogoggo" will also be counted? I am not sure tho. Best solution would be to not count the "dog" in "dogoggo" but still count the "dog" before the dot. I just went with the fscanf "solution". I would very appreciate your help tho if you can improve the code

Comment: @R0gue What about ["dog."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78004897/using-fgets-together-with-strcmp-strcmp-is-not-properly-comparing?noredirect=1#comment137525380_78004897) (with the `.`)? It seems you are conflating a _string_ with a _word_.  A _word_ does not have precise meaning in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are matching words and not complete lines, you should use `fscanf` instead of `fgets`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int searchAndCount(FILE *fp, const char *searchWord) {
    int count = 0;
    char buffer[4096];
    
    // %4095s means store up to 4095 characters into buffer
    // before the null terminator
    while (fscanf(fp, "%4095s", buffer) == 1) { 
        if (strcmp(buffer, searchWord) == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    int count;
    const char *str = "dog";
    
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("File couldn't open properly");
        return 1;
    }
    count = searchAndCount(fp, str);
    printf("The word 'dog' occurs %d times in the file\n", count);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to ignore punctuation, here is a more elaborate version:

```
int searchAndCount(FILE *fp, const char *searchWord) {
    int count = 0;
    char buffer[4096];
    
    // repeat indefinitely
    for (;;) {
        // consume any separators (sequences of non letters)
        fscanf(fp, "%*[^a-zA-Z]");
        // try and read the next word
        if (fscanf(fp, "%4095[a-zA-Z]", buffer) != 1)
            break;
        // test the target word
        if (strcmp(buffer, searchWord) == 0)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: This works ! Thank you. Can you tell me why we use "4095" instead of 4096? and what does ==1 mean for fscanf

Comment: 3 problems with posted code 1) Does not compile, extra `)`. 2) `fscanf(fp, "%4095s", fp)` is certainly amiss - reading into a file pointer. 3) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78004897/using-fgets-together-with-strcmp-strcmp-is-not-properly-comparing/78005123?noredirect=1#comment137523861_78005123) suggests that 3 should be returned, yet this code (amended to fix prior 2 issues) returns 2.

Comment: @R0gue: 40965 is the maximum length, which is one less than the size.  `== 1` means `fscanf()` has performed one successful conversion, so it has read one word.

Comment: @chqrlie The new solution seems to work. Altho its very complicated for me to understand could you elaborate what  ```for(;;){...``` is doing?

Comment: @R0gue: I added explanatory comments

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `strcmp()`, which can match if the entire line of input is *only* that,  use `strstr()` to look for multiple occurrences within a line.

Code below uses `s++` to count 4 when input line is `"ababa aba abax\n"` and key is `"aba"`.  If the count should have been 1, research `strtok()`.

```
size_t len = strlen(searchWord);
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp)) { 
  char *s = buffer;
  while ((s = strstr(s, searchWord)) != NULL) {
    count++;

    // Use s++ to search for keys within matches
    s++; // Resume searching at the next character.

    // OR continue at the end of the match.
    s += len);
  }
}
return count;
```

Comment: `s++` may cause overlapping matches to be counted multiple times, such as `aaa` occurring 3 times in `aaaaa`.  You should use `s += strlen(searchWord);` instead.

Comment: There is another problem: for the user test case, your approach will count `dog` 4 times in `dog dog dogoggo dog.` instead of 3 as expected.

Comment: The OP did expect 3: *But it keeps giving me 0 even tho the .txt file has the word dog three times in it*